# MySQL Query "Explain": How does the server estimate "filtered" value?

Tags: mysql, explain

**Table:**

```
create table film (
  id int not null primary key auto_increment, 
  film_name varchar(50)
);

create table film_actor (
  id int not null primary key auto_increment, 
  actor_id int, 
  film_id int, 
  foreign key (film_id) references film(id) on delete cascade
);
```

**Data:**

```
insert into film(film_name) values 
  ('Film A'), ('Film B'), ('Film C'), ('Film D'), ('Film E'), ('Film F'),  ('Film G'), ('Film H'), ('Film I'),
  ('Film J'), ('Film K'), ('Film L'), ('Film M'), ('Film N'), ('Film O'),  ('Film P'), ('Film Q'), ('Film R');

insert into film_actor(actor_id, film_id) values
  (1, 1), (2, 3), (3, 1), (4, 2), (5, 4), (6, 1);
```

**Query:**

```
explain select film.name, film_actor.actor_id 
from film 
  inner join film_actor 
on film.id = film_actor.film_id
where film.id = 2;
```

**Results:**

```
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: film
   partitions: NULL
         type: const
possible_keys: PRIMARY
          key: PRIMARY
      key_len: 4
          ref: const
         rows: 1
     filtered: 100.00
        Extra: Null
*************************** 2. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: film_actor
   partitions: NULL
         type: ref
possible_keys: film_id
          key: film_id
      key_len: 5
          ref: const
         rows: 1
     filtered: 100.00
        Extra: NULL
```

**Question:**

I think before `join` MySQL filter `film` table based on `where film.id=2` clause, that's why `explain` `ref` shows `const` and `explain` `rows` shows `1` .

Based on that, it's natural to infer that `explain` `filtered` should be a small number(maybe `5%` in this particular case) since every row except one is filtered out. But it shows `100%`.

Can anyone please explain this?